# CGRectMake Does not move image (Sometimes)

Tags: objective-c, image, logging, move, cgrectmake

When click on the image in my app and the image is at the top, the image will always move down perfectly. But when the image is at the bottom sometimes the image does not move up. Even though it does not move the process is still run and it logs as if it was at the top. I tried everything I know how to do but do you see anything wrong? Thanks!!

```
- (void )imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer 
{
    NSLog(@"imageTapped");

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"move" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    if (self.imgV.frame.origin.y == 20) {

        NSLog(@"Top");

        upOrDown = @"1";


        self.invalidateTheTimer = @"";
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        self.imgV.frame=CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-self.imgV.frame.size.height, self.imgV.frame.size.width, self.imgV.frame.size.height);
        self.vBottom.frame=CGRectMake(0, self.imgV.frame.origin.y+self.imgV.frame.size.height, self.vBottom.frame.size.width, self.vBottom.frame.size.height);

    } else if (self.imgV.frame.origin.y >= 507) {

        NSLog(@"Bottom");


        self.imgV.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, self.imgV.frame.size.width, self.imgV.frame.size.height);
        self.vBottom.frame=CGRectMake(0, self.imgV.frame.origin.y+self.imgV.frame.size.height, self.vBottom.frame.size.width, self.vBottom.frame.size.height);



        [hour setText:@""];
        [minute setText:@""];
        [second setText:@""];

        [timer invalidate];
        self.invalidateTheTimer = @"INVALIDATE";



    }

        NSLog(@"%f", self.imgV.frame.origin.y);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you haven't posted your entire code, it's hard to figure out what's wrong exactly, but looking at the mess you've made, I suggest you take a look into [block based animations](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) which should simplify what you're trying to accomplish.

Additionally, if I had to guess, I'd say the issue is in your timer and whatever method it's invoking is probably messing with your animations.